# feeling shoehorned: using joins in gorm

Tags: orm, go-gorm

Disclaimer: this is my first time using an ORM, and my SQL might be a bit rusty.

I have an application with users, songs, and I want to count and display how many times each song has been played by a given user. I know how to do it with SQL, but I'm failing at translating this to GORM. It goes like this:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/sqlite"
)

type User struct {
    ID       int `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Listened []Listen
}

type Song struct {
    ID       int `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Title    string
    Listened []Listen
}

type Listen struct {
    UserID int `gorm:"primary_key;auto_increment:false"`
    SongID int `gorm:"primary_key;auto_increment:false"`
    Count  int
}
```

Then, let's add some data

```
func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open("sqlite3", "test.db")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    db.DropTableIfExists(&User{}, &Song{}, &Listen{})
    db.CreateTable(&User{}, &Song{}, &Listen{})

    db.Save(&User{ID: 1})
    db.Save(&User{ID: 2})

    db.Save(&Song{ID: 1, Title: "oh yeah"})
    db.Save(&Song{ID: 2, Title: "greatest song"})
    db.Save(&Song{ID: 3, Title: "bestest song"})

    db.Save(&Listen{UserID: 1, SongID: 1, Count: 7})
    db.Save(&Listen{UserID: 1, SongID: 2, Count: 23})
    db.Save(&Listen{UserID: 2, SongID: 2, Count: 13})
    db.Save(&Listen{UserID: 2, SongID: 3, Count: 10})

    // do something here
}
```

Now, as I said I want to list how many times a user has played each song of the database. After scratching my head a little I came to this:

```
sqlite> select songs.id, l.count from songs
   ...> left join (select song_id, count from listens where user_id = 1) as l
   ...> on songs.id = l.song_id;
id          count     
----------  ----------
1           7         
2           23        
3
```

... and here I am. I just don't understand how I can express that with GORM method chains. Or should I just give up and run a raw sql query?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found how to do it:

`db.Table("songs").
    Select("songs.id, listens.count").
    Joins("left join (select * from listens where user_id = ?) as listens on songs.id = listens.song_id", 1).
    Find(&rs)`

Answer (score 0):

This query probably will work also. I hope it's helpful.

```
if err := db.Table("listens").Select("songs.id, listens.count").
Joins("JOIN songs on listens.song_id = songs.id").Where("user_id = ?", 
1).Find(&rs).Error; err != nil {
    fmt.Prinln(err)
}
```